# R regexpr word word capture

Tags: r, regex

I am trying to match the county name of a state in a string.

```
strings <- c("High School Graduate or Higher (5-year estimate) in Jefferson Parish, LA"
             ,"High School Graduate or Higher (5-year estimate) in Jefferson Davis Parish, LA")

countyName <- "Jefferson"
stateAbb <- "LA"

test <- gregexpr(paste0(countyName," (\\w), ",stateAbb,"$"),strings,ignore.case=T,perl=T)
```

I cannot get `test` to actually return anything.

The code works if I replace `\\w` with `.*` but then "Jefferson" will also match lines with "Jefferson Davis".

Of course, when the county Name is actually "Jefferson Davis", I want to match "Jefferson Davis"

Comment: What if you replace `(\\w)` with `(\\w+)`? Your first string will be matched then, is it the way you expect your code to work? See  [that regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/e3CLFM/1).

Comment: I know that `+` is the "match at least once" special character.  So using just `(\\w)` won't tell the engine to match once and only once?

Comment: `\w` matches a single letter, or digit or `_`. If you need to match 1 or more "word" chars, quantify it. `\w+` means *1 or more letters, digits, or `_` symbols.

Comment: Great!  Make this the answer and I will accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current regex only match a single "word" char (that is, a letter, digit or `_` symbol) after the *countyName*. To make it match 1 or more "word" chars, add a `+` quantifier to `\w`:

```
test <- gregexpr(paste0(countyName," (\\w+), ",stateAbb,"$"),strings,ignore.case=T,perl=T)
                                         ^
```

The resulting regex will look like

```
Jefferson (\w+), LA$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/e3CLFM/1)

**Details**:

- `Jefferson` - a literal substring
- - a space
- `(\w+)` - a capturing group (perhaps, you do not even need it, remove `(` and `)` if you do not need to access this submatch) matching 1 or more letters, digits or `_` symbols
- `,`  - a comma and then a sapce
- `LA` - a literal substring
- `$` - end of string.